Python FlickrAPI throwing exception on construction: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: oauthtokens"
There's nothing in the installation documentation about installing sqlite3, but if it's a dependency, it will have installed as part of the pip install process. I've manually installed sqlite3 so I have a command-line client I can poke at, but had no expectation that adding it would change anything.
I have version 2.1.2 of the api. I'm on python3.12.2 on an Ubuntu machine, but I get the same issue from Python 3.9 on OSX. I've double-checked the key and secret and they are correct. When I try to set up the interface object, just copying the code from the first example in the documentation:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import flickrapi

api_key = u'aoeuaoeuaoeu'
api_secret = u'natohueth'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

I just get an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ronb/flickr/./mvtags.py", line 10, in <module>
    flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret, db_name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flickrapi/core.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.flickr_oauth = auth.OAuthFlickrInterface(api_key, secret, self.token_cache)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flickrapi/auth.py", line 159, in __init__
    if oauth_token.token:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flickrapi/tokencache.py", line 175, in token
    curs.execute('''SELECT oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, access_level, fullname, username, user_nsid
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: oauth_tokens

